# Heap exploit fails: Memory corruption

Tags: c, linux, assembly, malloc, heap-memory

Currently learning heap exploitation but there is something weird I don't understand:

This is the next chunk to be allocated by a call to malloc(0x80):

```
0x602090:   0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000091
0x6020a0:   0x00007ffff7dd1b78  0x0000000000601120
...
```

Calling another malloc(0x80) after this, my goal is to get back 0x601130. This works, but only if 0x601128 == 0x90:

```
0x601120:   0x0000000000602010  0x0000000000000090
0x601130:   0x0000000000602130  0x00000000006021c0
```

If I change 90 to any other value, I get memory corruption:

```
*** Error in `censored': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000006021d0 **
...
#0  0x00007ffff7a42428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=0x6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007ffff7a4402a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff7a847ea in __libc_message (do_abort=0x2, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7b9de98 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff7a8f13e in malloc_printerr (ar_ptr=0x7ffff7dd1b20 <main_arena>, ptr=0x6021d0, 
    str=0x7ffff7b9acff "malloc(): memory corruption", action=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:5006
#4  _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7dd1b20 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=0x80) at malloc.c:3474
```

Here is the code in GLIBC_2.2.5, at malloc:3474:

```
bck = victim->bk;
if (__builtin_expect (chunksize_nomask (victim) <= 2 * SIZE_SZ, 0)
    || __builtin_expect (chunksize_nomask (victim)
         > av->system_mem, 0))
  malloc_printerr (check_action, "malloc(): memory corruption",
                   chunk2mem (victim), av);
size = chunksize (victim);
```

Now, from what I've read and my understanding of this code, the victim chunksize should be bigger than 2 * SIZE_SZ (so bigger than 16 bytes in 64bits) and smaller than av->system_mem. Here av->system_mem is equal to:

```
gdb-peda$ p av->system_mem
$1 = 0x21000
```

So I would expect any value between 0x10 and 0x21000 to pass that checks. Why does it not?

Comment: The address reported in the "memory corruption" message (`0x00000000006021d0`) doesn't seem to be part of the same `mchunkptr` structure as you're dumping (`0x602090`).  If the `mchunkptr` glibc was complaining about was at `0x602090` then I would expect that the address in the error message to be `0x00000000006020a0`.